# Export ical every 30 minutes

Tags: emacs, timer, org-mode

I'm trying to automate the creation of an ical file (the one I get after `C-c C-e c a`) every 30 minutes, to visualize it in a calendar app. Ideally, it should be done asynchronously to asynchronously. I tried adding this to my `.emacs` file

```
(run-with-timer 0 (* 30 60) 'org-icalendar-export-agenda-files async)
```

but it didn't work (as you can see, I have no idea of elisp).

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You probably want to quote the `async` argument. Other than that, the `run-with-timer` invocation seems OK to me (I'd use `#'org-icalendar-export-agenda-files` to indicate that it is a function, but it should work with just the quote). But `org-icalendar-export-agenda-files` is probably making assumptions about how it is called (e.g. what buffer can you call it from? can it be any buffer or does it have to be the buffer of an agenda file?) and that is probably causing your problems. Check the `*Messages*` buffer for error messages and update your question with them.

Comment: @NickD it turned out the problem was with the async execution. According to this https://superuser.com/questions/738492/org-mode-8-async-export-process-fails, you need a separate init file to execute the async export. I ended up removing the async paramater and it worked.